# missing project.properties file error

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development. As I'm learning, I've used a few of the sample projects provided with the Android SDK. I have already had the ApiDemos running on the emulator, but when I went to run it today (now yesterday) I have these 3 errors.

> Description
>
> (1) Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
>
> (2) The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class >file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project
>
> (3) The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

I have looked in the ApiDemos project folder in my workspace for the project.properties file and it does exist.

Here's what I've tried multiple times...
-fix project properties
-clean the project
-delete the project and re-create it

Please forgive if this seems too simple. I hope it is a simple problem. I'm just overwhelmed by the Eclipse IDE, so maybe your answer could help me understand it better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a file called *default.properties*?

Comment: I don't see that file in the workspace folder. where should I look for it?

Comment: If it is there, it should be in the project root (with the AndroidManifest.xml). It's probably not there though, just checking. *default.properties* has been renamed to *project.properties* some time ago, so I thought maybe you got an old sample with the old file and use a newer version of the android tools, which might lead to this error.

Comment: I just started Android development (or attempting to) 2 months ago, so everything is pretty current. Also the project.properties file is there in the treeview and in the workspace folder for ApiDemos

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have something like

```
sdk.dir=/Developer/AndroidSDK
```

in your `local.properties` file.

Also, by default `project.properties` file is pretty simple:

```
# Project target.
target=android-15
```

Comment: But it's pretty strange that these files are not created with `android` tool.

Comment: Thanks for quick responses so far. I apologize for not getting back sooner, I wasn't expecting a response so quickly so I decided to reinstall Eclipse, remove the API Demos and re-create it again. I'm back to the same 3 errors. I'm looking into your responses

Comment: forgive ignorance  where is the local.properties file

Comment: I should mention that the target SDK is 8.

Comment: I would appreciate more help on this. I will have to come back to check responses in a few hours as I have been up all night on this one and I need some sleep.  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

From the context menu on the Android Java project, please use **Android Tools->Fix Project Properties**.

If that does not help, you can change the settings in the file using a nice dialog by using the context menu again, this time selecting Properties->Android.

Comment: I have fixed the properties several times. No luck.

Comment: Here's what I've tried multiple times... -fix project properties -clean the project -delete the project and re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio you might have noticed that it doesn't create the project.properties file anymore. 
But sometimes it's needed, especially with CI servers like Jenkins.
In that case you can add it running this command in the project's folder:

```
android update project --path ./src/main/ --target android-19
```

Where **android-19** is the target you specified in your build.gradle file and **src/main** is the default path for AndroidManifest.xml